# Only 50 SoundCloud groups returned by GET

Tags: soundcloud

I have joined 92 groups in SoundCloud, but when I do an SC.get("/me/groups"....etc I only get 50 returned to me. When I do a

```
curl http://api.soundcloud.com/users/6999000/groups.json?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID
```

I only get 50 results returned to me? Any way to get the full number of group entries returned?

Answer (score 4):

There is an `offset` GET parameter that you can pass in order to retrieve tracks above the 50 items limit.

```
curl http://api.soundcloud.com/users/6999000/groups.json?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&offset=50
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop and offset to get all.

Pseudo code...

```
String url = "http://api.soundcloud.com/users/6999000/groups.json?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID";
getGroups(url);

int count = 50;
String newUrl = "http://api.soundcloud.com/users/6999000/groups.json?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&offset=50";
while( count < 92) {
    getGroups(newUrl);
    count = count + 50;
    }
```

Look at http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#pagination for more information on offsets.