# SoundCloud API only returns 50 items in a collection

Tags: get, soundcloud

I am trying to pull all followers of an artist with the following url :

```
"http://api.soundcloud.com/users/45146165/followers.json?client_id=Client_ID"
```

The given artist has more than 50 followers but the API call returns a max of 50 followers.

I have tried what was stated here : [Only 50 Soundcloud groups returned by GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212073/only-50-soundcloud-groups-returned-by-get), which is to add a offset=50 to the end of the url.

Even if I change the offset value to be higher or lower than 50, I still get 50 followers returned.

Does anyone know what can be done?

Comment: The api will probably always return maximum 50 followers. But if you use an offset, I would guess that the **next** 50 followers are returned?

Comment: @Stef you are right. I did not catch that. So I would need to use a loop to get all

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653826/get-all-comments-from-soundcloud-track/23661849#23661849

Answer (score 0):

Most results from our API are returned as a collection. The number of items in the collection returned is limited to 50 by default with a maximum value of 200. Most endpoints support a `linked_partitioning` parameter that will allow you to page through collections. When this parameter is passed, the response will contain a `next_href` property if there are additional results. To fetch the next page of results, simply follow that URI. If the response does not contain a `next_href` property, you have reached the end of the results.

Ref: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#pagination

```
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.0.0.js"></script> 
<script> 
SC.initialize({   client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID' });

var page_size = 100; 

SC.get('/tracks', { limit: page_size }).then(function(tracks) {   
    // first 100 tracks 
});

SC.get('/tracks', { limit: page_size, linked_partitioning: 1 }).then(function(tracks) {   
    // page through results, 100 at a time 
}); 
</script>
```